# Why doesn't timeout work in requests library?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests, response

I want to parse some data from many web sites. A part of my code is a function, which gets data from the requested URL.

This is my function, and as you can see, I set timeout for the `get` function.

```
import requests, re
from lxml import html
from requests_html import HTMLSession
from requests.adapters import HTTPAdapter
from requests.packages.urllib3.util.retry import Retry

def get_source(url):
    try:
        session = HTMLSession()
        retry = Retry(connect=0, backoff_factor=0.5)
        adapter = HTTPAdapter(max_retries=retry)
        session.mount('http://', adapter)
        session.mount('https://', adapter)
        response = session.get(url, verify=False, timeout=0.5)
        #response = session.get(url, verify=False, timeout=(0.5, 0.5))
        return response
    except requests.exceptions.RequestException as e:
        print(e)
        return None
```

But when I call this function for example with below URL, the execution time of the function is greater than 300 seconds.

`https://www.bjcta.org/wp-content/uploads/2021/02/Unified-Certification-Program-DBEs-Alabama.xls`

I don't know what the main problem is and how I can set a timeout to prevent increased execution time.

Answer (score 0):

I've checked your code, everything works perfectly.
If I change `timeout=0.1` it raises an exception.
The only thing I change is

```py
# this 
from requests.packages.urllib3.util.retry import Retry
# to this
from urllib3.util.retry import Retry
```

my code(which is yours actually):

```py
def get_source(url):
    try:
        session = HTMLSession()
        retry = Retry(connect=0, backoff_factor=0.5)
        adapter = HTTPAdapter(max_retries=retry)
        session.mount('http://', adapter)
        session.mount('https://', adapter)
        print("start")
        response = session.get(url, verify=False, timeout=0.5)
        # response = session.get(url, verify=False, timeout=(0.5, 0.5))
        print("done")
        return response
    except requests.exceptions.RequestException as e:
        print(e)
        return None

url = "https://www.bjcta.org/wp-content/uploads/2021/02/Unified-Certification-Program-DBEs-Alabama.xls" \

print(get_source(URL))
```

Otuput:

```sh
$ python stackOverflow/requests_timeout.py 
start
/home/gad/notes/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py:1013: InsecureRequestWarning: Unverified HTTPS request is being made to host 'www.bjcta.org'. Adding certificate verification is strongly advised. See: https://urllib3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced-usage.html#ssl-warnings
  warnings.warn(
done
<Response [200]>
```

with `timeout=0.1`

```sh
$ python stackOverflow/requests_timeout.py 
start
HTTPSConnectionPool(host='www.bjcta.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /wp-content/uploads/2021/02/Unified-Certification-Program-DBEs-Alabama.xls (Caused by ConnectTimeoutError(<urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x7f8b11e056d0>, 'Connection to www.bjcta.org timed out. (connect timeout=0.1)'))
None
```